# Azure Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -

Tags: azure, powershell

I am wondering if there is way to use the Invoke-AzVMRunCommand to run a single command, rather than a powershell ps1 file?

As an example, I want to execute a single command...  "C:\app\app.exe -c exit".  Without the need to push a powershell commandlet to the system.

I am able to do this via the Azure Portal "RunPowerShellScript" and it works but would like to do it to multiple systems via the command line via Invoke-AzVMRunCommand. These systems do not share a command account that can be used.

According to Microsoft, here is the syntax...

`Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName 'rgname' -VMName 'vmname' -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath 'sample.ps1' -Parameter @{param1 = "var1"; param2 = "var2"}`

I don't want to run a script, I merely want to be able to execute a command on the system.  Is this possible?

Comment: Could you please tell me what do you mean "would like to do it to multiple systems via the command line via Invoke-AzVMRunCommand"?  Besides, could you tell me what is your exe file? Is it an Installation package or your software?

Comment: dont really understand the question. you dont need to "push any cmdlets to the system" if you want to run an executable. it is just a shell, you can run anything with it

Comment: What he has is a jumbox, or a computer from which he has to execute a remote command to multiple VMs(computers). He probably doesn't want to have a script laying down on that jumpbox, but rather wants to execute a command remotely, and then forget about it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct way of doing it. But, you can write a script block and generate a file from it and then run Invoke-AzVMRunCommand using that file and later on delete that file if required.

```
$Server = "server01"
[System.String]$ScriptBlock = {Get-Process}
$FileName = "RunScript.ps1"
Out-File -FilePath $FileName -InputObject $ScriptBlock -NoNewline
$vm = Get-AzVM -Name $Server
Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $vm.ResourceGroupName -Name $Server -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath $FileName
Remove-Item -Path $FileName -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: where do you actually put the code to execute? eg Get-ChildItem -Path cert: -Recurse -ExpiringInDays 75...where does this go?

Comment: @itye1970 rest of the things will remain same. You just need to update the $ScriptBlock = {Get-Process}. `[System.String]$ScriptBlock = {Get-ChildItem -Path cert: -Recurse -ExpiringInDays 75}`

Answer (score 2):

It's now possible to use the:

> -ScriptString

... option, however you need to ensure that the Az version will support it.

Azure Pipelines as of 2022-07-21 don't support it:
"A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ScriptString'."

See the documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/invoke-azvmruncommand?view=azps-8.1.0